# Passing a float3 / vec3 to a shader via unity properties

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, glsl

I am writing a shader and I would like to pass a vec3 along to the input.
however everything I could find is always passing either a single float a vec4, texture or number range. Is it possible to send a vanilla vec3 along to a shader in unity?

```
Properties
{
    offset ("formula Offset", Vector) = (0, 0, 0)
}
```

Doesn't seem to work as I hoped.
To get it to compile I have been doing this:

```
Properties
{
    offset ("formula Offset", Vector) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
}

// offset.xyz //Extract relevant data from vector
```

this just doesn't feel right. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like when you mark a property as Vector it has to have 4 components. Even the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Properties.html) says: ***"Vector properties are displayed as four number fields."***

This really isn't as bad as it looks, just set the last components to zero.

---

Note that annoyingly the matching variable is NOT "vector", it's "float4".

Full list:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37749687/294884

Comment: I found a bonus that makes it look a little better 
when I declare it as a uniform in the shader, I just put vec3 and it ignores the extra value
I've also found the Shader.setGlobal method contains both matrixes and Vector3