# How to get full list of Unity shader properties

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine, cg

I am quite new to shaders and have been searching for a full list of Unity shader properties. I haven't found any such documentation. What I found was [SL-Properties](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Properties.html). Where can I find a full list of properties and their functions?

**UPDATE**

An example was given in [SL-Properties](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Properties.html) showing the list of properties for a water shader namely, `_WaveScale`, `_Fresnel`, `_BumpMap` and so on. Knowing these specific properties make it easier to arrive at a solution. I recently tried coding something similar to a stroke before I found out about the following properties.

```
fixed _Stroke;
half4 _StrokeColor;
```

Comment: I cannot find a way of getting list of a specific Shader's properties... Trying desperately to change my material's `BlendOp`...

Answer (score 4):

Unity has it's own shader syntax called [ShaderLab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Shader.html).

All the necessary information about it can be found on this [website](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Shader.html).

 As for the properties, check out this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PropertiesInPrograms.html).

As nvidia is [not supporting](https://developer.nvidia.com/cg-faq) CG anymore, latest unity versions actually compile shaders using [HLSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Bb509561(v=vs.85).aspx) compiler and transform the resulting bytecode to GLSL.
The CG shader code continues to work mostly unchanged. Nowadays you can take advantage of modern shader features, like compute shaders and tessellation, that weren't supported by CG, using HLSL syntax.

**For example these shader properties:**

```
_MyColor ("Some Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) 
_MyVector ("Some Vector", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
_MyRange ("My Range", Range (0, 1)) = 1
_MyFloat ("My float", Float) = 0.5 
_MyInt ("My Int", int) = 1 
_MyTexture2D ("Texture2D", 2D) = "white" {} 
_MyTexture3D ("Texture3D", 3D) = "white" {}
_MyCubemap ("Cubemap", CUBE) = "" {}
```

**would be declared for access in Cg/HLSL code as:**

```
fixed4 _MyColor;
float4 _MyVector;
float _MyRange;
float _MyFloat; 
int _MyInt;
sampler2D _MyTexture2D;
sampler3D _MyTexture3D;
samplerCUBE _MyCubemap;
```

Property types in ShaderLab map to Cg/HLSL variable types this way:

• Color and Vector properties map to **float4**, **half4** or **fixed4** variables.

• Range and Float properties map to **float**, **half** or **fixed** variables.

• Texture properties map to **sampler2D** variables for regular (2D) textures.

• Cubemaps map to **samplerCUBE**.

• 3D textures map to **sampler3D**.

Comment: how should I declare an **uint** in both properties and cg? I tried exactly like _MyInt (changing the type from int to uint, obviously) but it didn't compile.

Comment: You haven't really answered the question: where can one find a full list of the shader properties?

Answer (score 2):

The properties of a shader in Unity are just a public variables visible to the engine, because Cg shader is wrapped into ShaderLab program.

You can see the structure of a shader in Unity at this presentation of [Andy Touch](https://twitter.com/andytouch?lang=en): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zr1zQpdYG1Q&t=7m36s

So, when you see

`fixed _Stroke;
half4 _StrokeColor;`

later in your code it's just an actual variables that are used by Cg program and binded to these properties.

Check adjacent [Unity docs section](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PropertiesInPrograms.html) to get to know how these properties are mapped to shader variables.